# Reactjs default logo img url

Tags: reactjs, image, src

I am just starting out with Reactjs. The default code in the App.js file has the react logo. On inspecting the img tag for this logo in the browser, I see the following src url.

```
<img src="/static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg" class="App-logo" alt="logo">
```

But I dont find the "/static/media/" path anywhere in my local project directory, and I don't find the file 'logo.5d5d9eef.svg' anywhere either. Where is this image being served from?

Comment: JavaScript maps it to a different serve location. You have that as the `./src/logo.svg`.

Answer (score -1):

This logo you are seeing is being served from /src/logo.svg.

The static/media/ is being generated from how react builds and shows to the user.

Here is the intial create-react-app structure:

```
my-app
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

Here is where you can find some more documentation:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

It mostly about Webpack (which is used by create-react-app). As you can see the original file is named `logo.svg`. Webpack detects imports like `import logo from './logo.svg'` and transforms imported files into assets with suffix `logo.5d5d9eef.svg`. This is needed to make asset names unique. Please read about Webpack first.